# How is this linear regression calculated?

Tags: pine-script

While trying to translate a Pine Script indicator I got stuck at this line that calculates a linear regression with linreg().  Isn't a linear regression formula supposed to take in an array?

`val = linreg(source - avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, lengthKC)),sma(close,lengthKC)), 20,0)`

I want to use the trader_linearreg() function from the trader_php extension, but it takes in an array as the first argument.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reverse engineer the Sqeeze momentum from Tranding view right? I came here for the same and got stuck in the same place :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no arrays in pinescript. The basic type of data in Pine is a list of values, named `series`.

Also, Any expression that contains a series variable will be treated as a series itself.

Reference. [Type System](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Type_System)

A variable with series type holds all the previous values of the variable as well. You can access it with the [History Referencing Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Operators#History_Referencing_Operator_.28Square_Brackets_.5B.5D.29).

The signature of `linreg()` is:

```
linreg(source, length, offset) → series[float]

RETURNS
Linear regression curve.

ARGUMENTS
source (series) Source series.
length (integer) Length.
offset (integer) Offset.
```

In your example, the result of the following calculation is series type.

```
source - avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, lengthKC)), sma(close,lengthKC))
```

That is because:

> Any expression that contains a series variable will be treated as a
>   series itself.

Comment: thank you.. couldn't find reference of built-in variables.. So I would need to calculate the "series" first into an array and then run it through the linreg() function?

Comment: @user10745267Exactly. Series holds values of the previous bars, so you need to convert it into an array. When you want to read the reference manual, Ctrl + Click (PC) or Cmd + Click (Mac) on some function or variable in editor and the reference manual should pop-up. Then on the left hand side there is a tab called "Build-in variables". Or you can use the search function.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? the sma() value is it the same always or its the sma at the specific point in the series? ... ( I dont know if I explain myself correctly )

Comment: The way pine script works is; for every bar, your script will be re-executed. This means all the calculations take place again and again for every new bar. @user10745267 The way sma() works is; it calculates the average stock price over a certain period ("length"KC"). If, length is 7 for example, it needs 7 previous bars to be formed to do the calculation. But remember, your script gets executed for every new bar, so those 7 bars are not the same.

Comment: So I do need the sma at every n point.  Its what I thought.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. No problem.

Comment: But can you explain what's the logic within linreg(), I can see the signature but not the code. Generally with CTRL+Click it shows some pine logic for some functions, but not on this case.

Comment: @Yogurtu, unfortunately, the code is not public. However, the approach used in `linreg()` is called `least squares`. You can read more about the linear regression [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and more about the least squares method [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/least-squares-regression.html).